# jQuery infinite scroll and tumblr

Tags: jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm pretty new to tumblr so I've just been playing with the 'themes' currently I'm trying to introduce an infinite scroll. Here is the resources that I am using:

- Demo Tumblr: http://testingthemedes.tumblr.com/
- Infinite Scroll.js: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
- Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

You can hopefully see that I have gotten the masonry grid layout to work appropriately. I'm now trying to introduce the infinite scroll to extend the page and append the next page of content, I'm then trying to make sure that the masonry is called back to ensure that the new images are appended in the same layout.

here is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.0b2.120519/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js">
```

```
(function() {

// Main content container
var $container = $('#posts');

// Masonry + ImagesLoaded
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        // selector for entry content
        itemSelector: '.post'
    });
});

// Infinite Scroll
$container.infinitescroll({

    // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    navSelector  : "nav.pagination",
    // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    nextSelector : "nav.pagination a#next",
    // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    itemSelector : ".post",

    // finished message
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.'
        }
    },

    // Trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });

});

// Pause Infinite Scroll
$(window).unbind('.infscr');

// Resume Infinite Scroll
$('.next').click(function(){
    $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
    return false;
});

})();
```

This is only a snippet, to see the full code please check here as I cannot paste due to character limit: http://pastebin.com/hnpfmCLb

I'm finding this tricky as I'm seeing no errors in the console, but it just doesn't seem to be triggering and introducing the next page of content. I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes may be able to help me with the problem.
Many thanks in advance,
John

Comment: I've added the debugging mode so that you may check the console.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. This question is unfortunately very broad, as you're essentially asking people to go to pastebin and read your entire codebase, which as you've said is so large it doesn't fit in the question. That's a lot to ask of volunteers.

Comment: Hi @MikeMcCaughan, I've included the most prominent part of the code in my question, I added the pastebin link as an extra aid as I wanted to make my question as clear as possible. In short, I wasn't sure how many people would be familiar with tumblr. I'm sorry if the question seemed broad.